# Server version (5.5.40-MariaDB) does not match with the version of the server (10.0.15-MariaDB) with which this program was built/distributed

Tags: mysql-5.5, mariadb, centos

I just upgrade `MariaDB (Mysql) 5.5.40` to `MariaDB 10.0.15` by following this [step by step](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-upgrade-mariadb-5-5-to-mariadb-10-0-on-centos-7/). I have failed to enable the mysql and also `mysql_upgrade` with the following errors

`mysql_upgrade -u root -p --skip-version-check --debug-info`

```
User time 0.00, System time 0.00
Maximum resident set size 3256, Integral resident set size 0
Non-physical pagefaults 958, Physical pagefaults 0, Swaps 0
Blocks in 0 out 0, Messages in 0 out 0, Signals 0
Voluntary context switches 63, Involuntary context switches 1
ERROR 1911 (HY000) at line 64: Unknown option 'STATS_PERSISTENT'
ERROR 1911 (HY000) at line 68: Unknown option 'STATS_PERSISTENT'
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 580: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 583: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 735: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_waits_summary_by_host_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 736: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 737: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 748: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_waits_summary_by_user_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 749: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 750: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 762: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_waits_summary_by_account_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 763: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 764: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 869: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'socket_instances'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 870: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 871: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 899: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'socket_summary_by_instance'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 900: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 901: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 928: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'socket_summary_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 929: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 930: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 963: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'host_cache'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 964: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 965: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 986: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'objects_summary_global_by_type'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 987: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 988: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1015: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'setup_actors'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1016: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1017: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1043: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'setup_objects'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1044: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1045: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1096: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1097: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1098: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1140: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'table_io_waits_summary_by_table'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1141: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1142: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1219: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'table_lock_waits_summary_by_table'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1220: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1221: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1163 (42000) at line 1240: The used table type doesn't support BLOB/TEXT columns
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1255: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_stages_current'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1256: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1257: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1271: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_stages_history'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1272: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1273: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1287: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_stages_history_long'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1288: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1289: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1300: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_stages_summary_by_thread_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1301: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1302: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1313: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_stages_summary_by_host_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1314: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1315: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1326: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_stages_summary_by_user_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1327: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1328: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1340: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1341: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1342: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1352: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_stages_summary_global_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1353: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1354: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1398: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_statements_current'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1399: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1400: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1444: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_statements_history'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1445: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1446: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1490: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_statements_history_long'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1491: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1492: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1522: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_statements_summary_by_thread_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1523: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1524: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1554: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_statements_summary_by_host_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1555: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1556: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1586: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_statements_summary_by_user_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1587: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1588: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1619: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1620: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1621: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1650: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_statements_summary_global_by_event_name'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1651: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1652: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1659: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'hosts'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1660: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1661: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1668: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'users'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1669: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1670: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1678: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'accounts'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1679: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1680: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1713: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_statements_summary_by_digest'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1714: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1715: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1723: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'session_connect_attrs'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1724: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1725: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1729: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'session_account_connect_attrs'
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1730: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 1731: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

User time 0.00, System time 0.06
Maximum resident set size 2796, Integral resident set size 0
Non-physical pagefaults 872, Physical pagefaults 0, Swaps 0
Blocks in 0 out 216, Messages in 0 out 0, Signals 0
Voluntary context switches 173, Involuntary context switches 9403
```

Here what I found more in `/var/lib/mysql/localhost.err`

```
InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
150104 23:28:48 [ERROR] InnoDB: Can't open './ibdata1'
150104 23:28:48 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and$
150104 23:28:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150104 23:28:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150104 23:28:48 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 s$
150104 23:29:19 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria $
150104 23:29:19 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
150104 23:29:19 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150104 23:29:19 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
150104 23:29:19 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150104 23:29:19 [ERROR] Aborting

150104 23:29:19 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150104 23:29:19 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.pid ended
```

Hope this will assist to get the source of problems. Appreciate if anyone experience this willing to help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64708/discussion-on-question-by-muhaimin-server-version-5-5-40-mariadb-does-not-matc).